# iOS7 UIWindow wrong height after status bar hidden

Tags: iphone, ios7, uiwindow, uistatusbar, ios7-statusbar

I added an UIWindow with a subView of an UIView to current key window.

```
CGFloat width = 35;    
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - width, width, width)];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
self.window.hidden = NO;

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.window addSubview:view];
```

[image]

And when I called

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:sender.selected withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

In iOS7,  after the window has been added, **the window's height changed automatically to the screen's height**

[image]

So what may cause this problem?